# Unable to Launch the Neo4j Console App After Upgrade to macOS Big Sur

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

Yesterday, I upgraded my iMac to macOS Big Sur. When I attempted to launch the Neo4j Console app in Terminal, it returned a series of errors. I was running 3.5.20 of the Community Server.

I thought I could resolve these errors by installing the latest version of the Community Server. I downloaded and installed version 3.5.24. When I attempted to launch the 3.5.24 database, it returned the following errors, which are similar to those version 3.5.20 produced.

```
Starting Neo4j.
2020-11-17 12:36:06.242+0000 WARN  dbms.active_database is deprecated.
2020-11-17 12:36:06.275+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.5.24 ========
2020-11-17 12:36:06.299+0000 INFO  Starting...
2020-11-17 12:36:15.159+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@39993624' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by the expected signer! (Policy files are specific per major JDK release.Ensure the correct version is installed.)". Starting Neo4j failed: Component

'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@39993624' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by the expected signer! (Policy files are specific per major JDK release.Ensure the correct version is installed.)".
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@39993624' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by the expected signer! (Policy files are specific per major JDK release.Ensure the correct version is installed.)".
    at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:45)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:187)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@39993624' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by the expected signer! (Policy files are specific per major JDK release.Ensure the correct version is installed.)".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:473)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:180)
    ... 3 more
 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /Users/ciro/Applications/neo4j-community-3.5.24/data/databases
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:232)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:148)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityGraphFactory.newGraphDatabase(CommunityGraphFactory.java:41)
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:90)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    ... 5 more
 
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.bolt.BoltServer@e156110' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by the expected signer! (Policy files are specific per major JDK release.Ensure the correct version is installed.)".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:473)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:227)
    ... 9 more
 
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:518)
    at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getCipher(JsseJce.java:189)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.isTransformationAvailable(SSLCipher.java:483)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.<init>(SSLCipher.java:472)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher.<clinit>(SSLCipher.java:81)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:67)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuites(SSLContextImpl.java:345)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(SSLContextImpl.java:46)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:577)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1728)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1686)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.<clinit>(JdkSslContext.java:73)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:465)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:571)
    at org.neo4j.ssl.SslPolicy.nettyServerContext(SslPolicy.java:81)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltServer.createSslContext(BoltServer.java:202)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltServer.createProtocolInitializer(BoltServer.java:170)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltServer.lambda$createConnectors$0(BoltServer.java:149)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1321)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltServer.createConnectors(BoltServer.java:149)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.BoltServer.start(BoltServer.java:124)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
    ... 11 more
 
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:93)
    ... 45 more
 
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by the expected signer! (Policy files are specific per major JDK release.Ensure the correct version is installed.)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyPolicySigned(JarVerifier.java:336)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.loadPolicies(JceSecurity.java:378)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:323)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:50)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:85)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:82)
    ... 45 more
```

The database was running just fine before the upgrade. Has anyone experienced this error? Any ideas on how to get the Community Server database working again?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Ciro

Comment: We were not advised to upgrade to Big Sur because of compatibility issues. just for info.

Comment: Thanks...seems I did not get that advice.